# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Zone

Tags: angular

I am trying to write unit test cases for angular 4 using angular testTBed. As soon as I add this line testbed.configureTestingModule, I get this error `phantomjs 2.1.1 (windows 8.0.0) error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Zone`". I have no idea what's missing. I can see that  "zone.js": "^0.8.4" is added to my package.json in dependencies and devDependencies section. I am block at this basic step. I would really appreciate any help.

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        })
        }));
```

Comment: Did you set up a project using the cli? The cli adds a file name `test.ts` in there, zone is important. I'd assume you do not use the cli or that file, so you would have to manually import zone like this: `import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';`

Comment: yes it's not a cli project. I am writing an angular library. I tried importing it separately as you mentioned and still same error. I think my overall setup is not correct. Is there any blog or sample github project I can refer?

Comment: Don't really have a blogpost that I can reference, I bet google can find you something interesting. But you might consider using the cli, it's now ready to be used for libraries as well. Takes away a lot of the heavy lifting :)